# Windows number keys stopped working

Tags: windows, keyboard

Since about a day now, the 6, 8 and 9 number keys (the ones on top of the keyboard, the numpad works fine) only sometimes produce an actual input. However they to work if they are held down as another key is typed and also sometimes they just randomly work for a few seconds.

Things I did to resolve/understand the issue:

- disable/enable numlock
- turn off mouse keys
- run troubleshooter on keyboard
- run troubleshooter on laptop
- check for keyboard driver updates
- check for system updates
- reboot the laptop
- disable filter keys
- disable use numeric keypad to move mouse
- write a java application to see if any inputs were received (nope)

I know some of these points are related to the numpad, but I was desperate. Any help is appreciated, as it is quite annoying having to copy brackets all the time.

Comment: Try a USB Keyboard to help determine if you have a faulty laptop keyboard.

Comment: @John I do not possess another keyboard

Comment: See if you can borrow a keyboard from a friend (take the laptop to their place).

Comment: @John Ok I will do that first thing tomorrow, thanks

Comment: Since it's only a few keys, physically close together, as @John implies, this is most likely a hardware issue, so check by using another keyboard temporarily. Some replacement laptop keyboards can be found for US$10 or so, and many are easily replaced, needing only a s=few turns of a screwdriver. See your laptop's repair manual, online.

Comment: The keyboard might need cleaning.

Comment: I now have connected a bluetooth keyboard to my laptop, which worked perfectly. So I suppose I will try clean the keys and if that doesnt work replace my keyboard. Thank all of you for your help

Answer (score 0):

> I now have connected a bluetooth keyboard to my laptop, which worked
> perfectly.

So the problem of keys not working is a hardware problem (substituting a good keyboard worked).

Cleaning the keys:  Use care. May or may not work.

Best solution:  Replace the keyboard (usually and inexpensive repair)